# OpenERP - RML - force not to ignore white space?

Tags: xml, whitespace, odoo, rml

I've written this method:

```
def letterSpacing(self, field):
    spaced = ''
    for index in range(len(field)):
        if index != len(field)-1:
            spaced += '%s  ' % (field[index])                
        else:
            spaced += '%s' % (field[index])
    return spaced
```

It is used to space alphanumerics. I need to use use two spaces between them, but rml strips all additional white space (also I didn't find anything in rml  that would let you space letters like that, so thats why I've written this method). So it does not matter how much spaces I add, it still leaves one space.

Is there a way to force not ignore white space on my method? Because my method outputs spaces normally.

P.S. I also read that It does not ignore inside strings. But then I don't understand what rml considers strings and how could I make it think it is string? I tried wrapping input with `str()`, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

To force space ignore, use xpre instead of para in your rml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-breaking space instead of standard space. To type non-breaking space, please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Keyboard_entry_methods